# ng-pattern does not work when I generate it using Form builder of FOSUserbundle

Tags: javascript, angularjs, symfony, fosuserbundle

I'm trying to override change password form of Fosuser bundle and I want to display error message using AngularJS when the password doesn't fit my pattern 
I tried to add ng-pattern to form builder but nothing happens when I test with wrong format of password ..here is my code :

```
$builder->add('plainPassword', 'repeated', array(
        'type' => 'password',
        'options' => array('translation_domain' => 'FOSUserBundle'),
        'first_options' => array('attr'=>array('name' => 'first','data-ng-model'=>'pfirst',
            'placeholder' => 'enter your password',
            'ng-pattern' => "^(?=.*?[A-Z])(?=.*?[a-z])(?=.*?[0-9])(?=.*?[?!-/_/=:;§]).{8,20}$/")),

        'second_options' => array('label' => 'confirmation','pattern' => "/^(?=.*?[A-Z])(?=.*?[a-z])(?=.*?[0-9])(?=.*?[?!-/_/=:;§]).{8,20}$/"),

        'invalid_message' => 'fos_user.password.mismatch',
    ));
```

Comment: does pattern work when you manually create html and test it in angular?

Comment: yes it works very well

Comment: so what is different in the back end generated html?

Comment: Idon't know I tested this ' <form name="myform" data-ng-submit="create()">
                    <input
                           name="price_field"
                           data-ng-model="price"
                           ng-pattern="/^(?=.*?[A-Z])(?=.*?[a-z])(?=.*?[0-9])(?=.*?[?!-/_/=:;§]).{8,20}$/"
                           required
                    >
                    <span  ng-show="myform.price_field.$error.pattern">Not valid number!</span>
                    <input type="submit" class="btn">
                </form>' and it works

Comment: does `required` show up on other one? Doesn't seem to be an option you set

Comment: It seems you're missing `/` before your pattern in php form.

Comment: yes required wokrs

Comment: even if i add / still the same issue ... it works with pattern but ng-pattern no

Comment: The missing `/` in the beginning of the `ng-pattern` is essential. You can't have one at the end of the string and not have one at the beginning. Furthermore, having `/` inside the regex without escaping it would probably have bad/undesired consequences.

Comment: I wonder if I have to use any statement here ?